# Json deserializeObject

Tags: c#, json

Hi I want to deserialize this Json :

```
{
  "engine_name": "Hermle",
  "criterion": {
    "squareness": {
      "name": "perpendicularité",
      "theoretical": "5",
      "expected": "5"
    },
    "backlash": {
      "name": "jeu à l'inversion",
      "theoretical": "5",
      "expected": "5"
    },
    "straightness": {
      "name": "rectitude",
      "theoretical": "1",
      "expected": "1"
    },
    "spindle-runout": {
      "name": "faux rond broche",
      "theoretical": "5",
      "expected": "5"
    },
    "circularity": {
      "name": "circularité",
      "theoretical": "5",
      "expected": "5"
    }
  }
}
```

I have my class object :

```
public class SmartDevice
{
    public string Engine_name { get; set; }
    public Object criterion { get; set; }
}
```

This works great but I can't have Count propertie for criterion Object so I want to have a list of criterion but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: maybe declare as List<Object> criterion, instead??

Comment: @apomene but it isn't a list.

Comment: What about using int theoretical, expected? You have only two, same criterias in your json

Comment: When I declare criterion as a List<Object> it says : Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Comment: This is because criterion is an object and not a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go with a `Dictionary<string, object>` or instead of `object` go with a custom type like `CriteriaObject`.

Comment: FYI: Any object in JSON can always be represented via `Dictionary<string, object>`

Comment: ok and if I want to make a custom type how can I do this ? I tried this :
        public partial class Criterion
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public Crit crit { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class Crit
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string theoretical { get; set; }
            public string expected { get; set; }
        }

Comment: Why partial? Btw: If you use Newtonsoft.Json 10+ (?) you don't need to write it lower case: `expected` (json) => `Expected` (c#)

Comment: no need partial and I didn't know for lower case thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you define the problem, it's imposible to get count from criterion because it is an object and not a list or an array.
To be able to have a criterion list you need something like this:

```
{
  "engine_name": "Hermle",
  "criterion": [
    {
     "type": "squareness",
      "name": "perpendicularité",
      "theoretical": "5",
      "expected": "5"
    },
    {    
     "type": "circularity",
      "name": "circularité",
      "theoretical": "5",
      "expected": "5"
    }
  ] 
}
```

And the class should look like this:

```
public class SmartDevice
{
    public string Engine_name { get; set; }
    public List<Object> criterion { get; set; }
}
```